# MACRO Debug for pivot table

Tags: macros, pivot

Trying to create a MACRO to run a pivot table and I need help debugging.  Here is the script:

Sheets.Add
    newsheet = ActiveSheet.Name

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    dataname, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=newsheet & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2" _
    , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
Sheets(newsheet).Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .DisplayErrorString = False
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .EnableDrilldown = True
    .ErrorString = ""
    .MergeLabels = False
    .NullString = ""
    .PageFieldOrder = 2
    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RowGrand = True
    .SaveData = True
    .PrintTitles = False
    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
    .TotalsAnnotation = False
    .CompactRowIndent = 1
    .InGridDropZones = True
    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
    .DisplayContextTooltips = True
    .ShowDrillIndicators = True
    .PrintDrillIndicators = False
    .AllowMultipleFilters = True
    .SortUsingCustomLists = True
    .FieldListSortAscending = False
    .ShowValuesRow = True
    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
    .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Status")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Status"), "Count of Status", xlCount
```

End Sub

The error message I receive is run-time error 1004
application-defined or object-declined error
The line that is the issue is below:
 .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False

How do I correct?  Thanks!!!